# Django models : ForeignKey to ManyToMany "through" model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, database-schema

In a Django project that I am working on, I would like to have the following relationship between models -

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    c_through = models.ManyToManyField(through=C)

class C(models.Model):
    ...

class D(models.Model):
    b_model = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

I just wanted to make sure if this is possible as I could not find an example elsewhere and wanted to know if there would be anything serious I should keep in mind before going ahead with such a relationship.

Comment: Yes you can do like that

Comment: Not sure if you're aware but the `othermodel` positional argument required on `ManyToManyField` is missing, you can't have a *many-to-many* relationship without defining the model on the other end. Also, take into account that by using a custom `through` model Django won't be able to auto-create relationships for you as specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).